# Is it possible to regulate the amount of counter torque in a generator?

Tags: generator, torque, back-emf

I have a question for a machine I am working on,

The machine is used to pre-tension steel wire ropes for maritime uses, the wire rope sits on a drum with a 2m diameter. The tension has to be adjustable to anywhere between 50 to 200kN. The wire rope will be spooled by a ship winch. The rotational speed of the drum will have to be about 0,3 rad/s but if it's possible to do it faster while still maintaining the tension that would also be an option.

One of my ideas for this was to use a generator coupled to the drum so that the energy taken from the drum's rotation could be converted to power, while simultaneously producing a counter-torque to the drum's rotation. The electric energy I could then maybe find a use for, or just convert it to heat in a resistor bank.

Now my knowledge about electrical systems is very limited and I'm curious if this is even possible? I think this concept relates a lot to regenerative braking systems but I'm uncertain if the counter-torque will be adjustable enough for my application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the range of rotation speeds of the drum when the rope needs to be under tension? You aren't going to be able to apply meaningful "regenerative braking" if the tensioning ever needs to happen while the rope is static, but there might be a meaningful outcome if this is only done while the drum is rotating.

Comment: The wire rope will be spooled by a ship winch. The rotational speed of the drum will have to be about 0,3 rad/s but if it's possible to do it faster while still maintaining the tension that would also be an option.

Comment: It might be worth editing this into your question so it's visibly present for anyone with the right background to give a solid answer.

Comment: Note many generator and alternator types include a DC "field" winding to produce the reluctant magnetism. This field current can be varied, which affects the mechanical loading of the generator and resulting power output. Controlling tension means controlling field current.

Comment: Generally yes. In a motor or generator, voltage corresponds to speed and current corresponds to torque. With the right electronics you can fix one or the other, or set up any voltage/current curve you want.

Comment: 0.3 rad/s x 400kNm is about 130kW or 200 horsepower. Sorry to be a skeptic but I think that so much power at such low speed is going to be challenging to harness.

Comment: The drum has a 2m diameter, I assume you multiplied the force with the 2m to get that torque but in reality, it'll be half that, so 200kNm.